# message.author.id TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Why i didnt get `message.author.id` and create the channel with special permissions?

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { Client, Permissions } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    //Create the Command 
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("veranstaltung")
        .setDescription(`erstelle eine Veranstaltung`)
        .addStringOption(option1=> option1.setName("name").setDescription("Der Name der Veranstaltung").setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option2=> option2.setName("datum").setDescription("Das Datum der Veranstaltung").setRequired(true)),
    async execute(message){
        const name = message.options.get("name").value
        const Datum = message.options.get("datum").value
        const userid =


            //Create the Channel with Permissions
            message.guild.channels.create('new-voice', {
                type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: message.author.id,
                        deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
                    },
                ],
            })
            .then(
                message.reply ("Der Kanal " + name + " am " + Datum + " Wurde erfolgreich erstellt")
                )

            }

}
```

Comment: const userid = is removed thats not the Problem...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using interactions.
To access the user object, use `Interaction.user`, not Interaction.author (this is used in message commands).
So, to access the author id, use the following:

```
message.user.id
```

Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=user

Answer (score 0):

Slash commands are not message, they are `interaction`. So you should use your handler as `interactionCreate` and in your command file you'll edit all things according to interaction. Whenever you want to get id whos used command, you'll use;

```js
interaction.user.id
```

You can look [docs](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands) for more info.